# Linq how to filter an object list based on overlap of nested list property and external list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the object classes below.  How can setup a linq query to filter the `myItems` list to only return items that have `ItemGroups` with a `CategoryId` that is in the `categories` list?  So in my sample data below, I want my linq query to only return the item with `ItemId = 1` since it is the only item that has an itemgroup with a `CategoryId` that is in the `categories` list.

I have tried the following, but that does not seem to work:

```cs
myItems.Where(i => categories.Contains(i.ItemGroups.Select(g => g.CategoryId)))
```

```
public ItemGroup{
    int ItemGroupId
    int CategoryId
}

public class Item(
    int ItemId;
    List<ItemGroup> ItemGroups
)

List<int> categories {2,5,7}
List<Item> myItems = [
    {
        ItemId = 1,
        ItemGroups = [
            {
                ItemGroupId = 1,
                CategoryId = 1
            },
            {
                ItemGroupId = 2,
                CategoryId = 2
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        ItemId = 2,
        ItemGroups = [
            {
                ItemGroupId = 3,
                CategoryId = 3
            },
            {
                ItemGroupId = 4,
                CategoryId = 4
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `Any` on `ItemGroup` within the `Where` predicate

```cs
myItems.Where(i => i.ItemGroups.Any(g => categories.Contains(g.CategoryId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach where Linq operations are nested one level, rather than two.

For each `Item`, [`.IntersectBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersectby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-intersectby-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1)))) is used to determine its collection of `ItemGroup`s whose `CategoryId` is present in `categories`. If any such `ItemGroup` is present, the `Item` will be included.

```csharp
IEnumerable<Item> filteredItems = myItems
    .Where(i => i.ItemGroups
        .IntersectBy(categories, gr => gr.CategoryId)
        .Any());
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ROXGn).